# rigging in combination with GN

Tags: rigging, geometry-nodes

I want to control my IK target (cube) with GN.

Unfortunately if i move my cube by GN the rig won't move with it. If i move the cube manually, it works, the rig moves with it.

Looks like i am still too tired or still don't understand some basic principles here...

[image]

[image]

So what do i have to do that i can control my rig via GN?

I tried: setting the GN before and after the armature modifier...won't work too :( and of course like here in the pictures move the cube by its own GN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have an IK structure, with a cube, but that structure only responds to *transformation* of the cube-- moving it in object mode-- while our GN modifiers are instead *deforming* the cube-- moving the vertices inside its existing object space, without changing the actual orientation of that space.  And we want the IK to respond to the deformation.  What can we do?

[image]

IK is always going to work on the transformation, but we can make another bone that captures the deformation.  So we'll start by adding a new bone in our armature, that's unparented to anything, and we'll designate this new bone as our IK target instead of the cube.

Now, we need a way for the bone to acquire the location of the cube's actual vertices.  We can do that by creating a vertex group and assigning all of our vertices in Cube to that vertex group.  I'll call that vertex group "o" for origin.

Then, we'll give our new IK target bone a copy location constraint, targeting the cube, and we'll specify "o" as the vertex group.  When it sees that the constraint is using a vertex group, it won't copy the location of the object; instead, it will copy the weighted, average location of vertices assigned to "o":

[image]

This is assuming we only care about location for our IK target, which is usually the case.  If we care about rotation as well, we can create two new vertex groups on our cube but only assign *some* of our vertices to these groups, then damped track and locked track these vertex groups in the same way that we copied position from "o":

[image]

So we're rotating our cube in a GN transform node, and our new IK target is acquiring that rotation, first by pointing its -Z axis at the face we marked with vertex group "z", then by rotating about its Z axis to point its X axis at the face we marked with "x".

This technique can be used in nearly any situation to get deformation into a bone's transform.  You will often see people using "child of" or "copy rotation" constraints with vertex groups in lieu of the damped track+locked track I recommend, but that won't always work, because vertices don't really have rotation-- the rotation of a group of vertices is ambiguous.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your long answer. Maybe i am too dumb to understand your answer....but are you sure you answered on "I want to control my IK target (cube) with GN." ? because i don't see any IK Target in your answer or how the ik target and therefore my bone would move with it....i understand your answer as...how can i move my whole object with gn...but i might miss it because my knowledge is limited. A blend file with an ik target which will be steered by GN would would help me a lot. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, yes.  I'll edit this to a different answer.

Comment: great, works like a charm! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Watch the origin of the cube when you change transform node translation values: It doesn't move.  But IK uses the origin of the object, not the position of the mesh, so you would need a geometry node that moves the origin.  It doesn't current exist (see [this post](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/THgbbc/?sorting=hot) on right click select,) but it is being discussed for future reference.

You don't need geometry nodes to move the cube procedurally, of course. You could use custom properties and drivers, or several other approaches.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I would like to use GN to do that, so I just hope the node will come soon

Comment: Me too. It would allow a lot of cool procedural rigging; especially for things like GN generated cables.

Comment: Nice catch with the moving origin point - never noticed that! +1